# Which one is correct to use in my sentence? (That/ in which/ where)

Tags: grammar, word-usage

> This website is a kind of platform (**that**/ **in which**/ **where**) you can manage all your accounts.

Comment: **In/on which** and **where** mean the same thing. **That** doesn't have the meaning of 'in a place'.

Comment: Yes, "on which"and "where" are correct (and synonymous here) but not "that". This use of "where" demonstrates and reinforces its classification in modern grammar as a preposition meaning "in/to/from some place/thing".

Comment: Note also that _that_ is not a relative pronoun; it's a meaningless subordinator serving simply to introduce certain relative clauses.

Answer (score 0):

'This website is a kind of platform **on which** (or **where**) you can manage all your accounts.'

On/in which= where

This is the hotel **which/that** he likes most. (NOT where)

This is the hotel **in which**(or **where**) we stayed. (NOT that)